# How to conjugate "se succéder" with the noun?

Tags: grammaire, accord, participe-passé, verbes-pronominaux

I do not know how to conjugate verbs with "se". For instance, shall I write:

> Les années se sont succédées

or

> Les années se sont succédé

Comment: Just a note, verbs aren't "declined", they're "conjugated" (*conjuguer* in French).

Answer (score 5):

The verb [succéder](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/succ%C3%A9der) requires the preposition "à", for example, "succéder à quelqu'un". In the construction "succéder à quelqu'un", "quelqu'un" is not a direct object, so there will be no agreement between a direct object and the past participle of "succéder" in the past tense. For this reason, one should write "Les années se sont succédé" ("se" refers to "années", as if the sentence were a reformulation of "Les années ont succédé **aux** années précédentes").

This is often a source of confusion; see the article [Se succéder au participe passé](http://academie-francaise.fr/se-succeder-au-participe-passe) on the website of the Académie française.

The same rule applies to **other verbs with the preposition "à"**, for example: parler à quelqu'un, promettre quelque chose à quelqu'un:

- Elles se sont parlé pendant une heure.
- Elles se sont promis de rester amies.

Prononominal verbs (of which reflexive verbs are a subcategory) are conjugated with the auxiliary "être" and there is agreement in number and gender between the reciprocal pronoun and the past participle. (In this specific context, I use the term ["reciprocal pronoun"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_pronoun) instead of "reflexive pronoun" because "se" here expresses "each other" instead of "themselves".)

For example:

- Elles se sont rencontrées à Gand.
- Après un long silence, elles se sont revues le 21 juillet.

However, the verbs "rencontrer" and "revoir" don't need "à" to introduce their grammatical object.

Comment: +1 pour ta maîtrise des bizarreries du participe passé avec les verbes pronominaux. *Succéder* étant, dans cet exemple conjugué **pronominalement**.